# Simple file upload with Node.js

Tags: node.js, file-upload

I am building a node.js application that uses pdf.js to read pdf files, but much like other js, pdf.js does not allow cross origin requests. So, I need a way to save files selected with a file input to my pdf directory. I'm not so great with node so make it as simple as possible if you can.

Comment: please post your code so we can help.

Comment: I don't have any code regarding the upload yet. Would you mind posting the the code for this POST route? Or refer me to a helpful documentation of an npm library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic idea of what you need:

1st, require and use module 'connect-multiparty'. This will expose the req.files object in node.

```
var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
app.use(multiparty({});
```

Then, in your controller method, require the 'fs' module, and use it to save the uploaded file.

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFileSync("myFileName", req.files.file.ws.path, function(err) {
    if(err) { console.log(err); }
    else { console.log("file uploaded"); }
});
```

Being familiar with node will help, but the two basic libraries you need to perform this are the aforementioned https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-multiparty and http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

edit: see the link in the comments below. this answer is incomplete and is better explained in the link

Comment: Also, what does file.ws.path mean? What do I have to replace those with?

Comment: The file.ws.path should be where the uploaded file is stored in the /tmp folder, I believe. The first part (app.use) should be in your application, and the second should be in your post method. A few things that I forgot: 

in your html form, make sure you have "enctype="multipart/form-data", and make sure to name the input field "file".

Comment: so, my answer above isn't completely correct. see this link (which uses an old version of express, but using multiparty should fix that) http://howtonode.org/really-simple-file-uploads . You need to first read the file, then write it.